# Detect crawnling bots?

Tags: php

I need an if statement that will include a file on my page only if it detects crawlers from google, bing and yahoo. I found this code on another post but I want to add bing and yahoo too:

```
if(strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), "googlebot"))
{
    //MY CODE
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could solve this problem for me.

Comment: Not sure what your intentions are but this is not good web design and could seriously hurt PR.

Comment: I just want to include some links to pages such as reddit, facebook and pinterest to get backlinks from them quicker.

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Crawler user-agents can be found [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Crawlerlist/). Filtering out the ones you want should be trivial. On a sidenote, don't use `strstr()` for these kind of checks, `strpos()` is [faster and less memory intensive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). And you should typecheck against `FALSE`, because either function may return a value that evaluates to `false`.

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
if (strpos($ua, "googlebot") !== false || strpos($ua, "bingbot") !== false || … ) {
    // do something
}
```